# Is it possible to represent a plane with two parallel lines?

Tags: geometry

Only one plane passes through $y=x$ and $y=x+1$.
If its wrong then why so?
Is there any other plane that passes through these two lines?

Comment: Any three noncollinear points define a plane.  Can you find three noncollinear points on a pair of parallel lines?

Comment: What you write are planes in $R^3$. So the intersection,  if any, is a line and from a line pass uncountable many planes.

Comment: Give him some + to be abale to make comments.

Comment: @dmtri Oi... I didn't even think about that–I read the title of the question and kind of ignored the rest of it.  Prashanth CN: This does need clarification.  You ask about two parallel lines, but the equations that you have given do you not define lines in higher dimensional spaces.  In three-dimensional space, each of those equations defines a plane.  More generally, those equations define hyperplanes of codimension 1.

Comment: @ResidentDementor New users cannot generally comment, but they can comment on their own questions and answers. This is explained in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) on the main meta.

Comment: If the problem is 2D, there is only one plane and any line lies in it.

If the problem is 3D, you didn't specify the equations of two lines.

Comment: Why so many upvotes for a question that is meaningless ?

Comment: @Yves Daoust: The question isn't meaningless. The only "problem" I see, is that the two lines given as an example, were not given in their 3D version.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [two parallel lines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(geometry)#Determination_by_contained_points_and_lines) is one way to determine a plane. But, as stated in the comments, the lines must be given in their [3D version](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/404440/what-is-the-equation-for-a-3d-line).

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is 2D, there is only one plane and any line lies in it.

If the problem is 3D, you didn't give the equations of two lines !