# Intuition / Proof behind Affine Set taking form of a line geometrically

Tags: multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis

I'm independently studying Boyd & Vandenberghe's *Convex Optimization* and came across the following statement.

> Suppose $x_1 \ne x_2$ are two points on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Points of the
>   form $$y = \theta x_1 + (1 - \theta)x_2$$ where $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$,
>   form the *line* passing through $x_1$ and $x_2$.

I understand intuitively how this is a line where $n = 2$ (i.e. you can write it in slope-intercept form with $m = x_1 - x_2$). But what about for more than two dimensions (i.e. $n \gt 2$)? Why is this guaranteed to be a line geometrically for *any* $n$?

Comment: Can you picture it in $\mathbb R^3$?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. Can you clarify?

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/404440/what-is-the-equation-for-a-3d-line) help?

Comment: It helps outline the different possible forms. Thank you for the link, @J.W.Tanner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vector $v=x_2-x_1$ is a direction vector of the line. 
If, from the origin, we first go to point $x_1$, then take a vector of direction $v$, which is just $\lambda v$ for a scalar $\lambda$, then we arrive to a point on the line:
$$x\ =\ x_1+\lambda v\ =\ x_1+\lambda(x_2-x_1)\ =\ (1-\lambda)x_1+\lambda x_2$$
and every point on the line arises this way. 
(For swapping $x_1,x_2$, just take $\theta:=1-\lambda$.)