# Equation for line parallel to z-axis and intersects x-axis at (x=k, y=0, z=0)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

How would I pick $a,b,c$ to create a line that is parallel to $z$-axis and intersects $x$-axis at point $x=k, y=0, z=0$?

$$
ax+by+cz=d
$$

Comment: Your equation $ax+by+cz=d$ is for a plane

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the equation for a 3D line?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/404440/what-is-the-equation-for-a-3d-line)

Comment: I'm asking what's the special case for a line equation that's orthogonal to both x-axis and y-axis. and k units distance from z-axis.

Comment: $ax + by + cz = d$ is the equation of a *plane* in $\mathbb{R}^3$. To define a line you need two linear equations - the line is then the intersection of the two planes. In this case the two planes are $x=k$ and $y=0$..

Comment: So for example the following: $$(x,y, z) = (1/2, 0, t)$$ is a line orthogonal to xy-plane and parallel to z-axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, line passes through (k,0,0) and is parallel to z-axis so, the equation of line is $(x,y,z) = (k,0,0) + \alpha$(0,0,1), $\alpha \epsilon \mathbb{R}$

Comment: If i'm understanding correctly, its a "parametric vector equation" because otherwise **you need a system of "n - 1" equations to describe a line in n-dimensions.**.  But, really a "parametric vector equation" is really a vector represents of 3 equations, where 1 of the equations is linearly dependent, and 2 are linearly independent, leading to a parametric variable "$\alpha$" in your case. (but, more commonly the variable "t")