# Lines $\frac{x−x_0}{a_1}=\frac{y−y_0}{a_2}=\frac{z−z_0}{a_3}$ and $\frac{x−x_0}{b_1}=\frac{y−y_0}{b_2}=\frac{z−z_0}{b_3}$ if $a_1b_1+a_2b_2+a_3b_3=0$

Tags: calculus, geometry, multivariable-calculus, vectors, 3d

I think this is a really interesting question. I think that we could create a system of equation that would prove that the two lines are parallel but I am not entirely sure. Anyone knows how to tackle this question?

> What can you conclude about the lines
> $$\frac{x − x_0}{a_1} = \frac{y − y_0}{a_2} = \frac{z − z_0}{a_3}  \quad\text{and}\quad \frac{x − x_0}{b_1} = \frac{y − y_0}{b_2} = \frac{z − z_0}{b_3}$$
> given that $a_1b_1 + a_2b_2 + a_3b_3 = 0$?

Comment: Do you recognise the equation after “given that”? What have you learned about vectors and operations between two vectors?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use the [basic tutorial and quick reference guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Please make titles informative as to the mathematical content of your post, not the emotional content of your brain.

Comment: Hint: You can read off the direction of the line from the equation in symmetric form; the condition given is a condition on how the two directions relate, in a fairly obvious way. See [this post about the equation of a line in 3-space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/404440/what-is-the-equation-for-a-3d-line)

Comment: Benjamin Wang  Is that the dot product?